# Moving a single feature to production!

Tags: version-control, production

I am working on an API that is triggered using a custom Job scheduler. The API is in the form of .NET dll. Currently it contains 10-15 methods. Most of the methods are currently in testing phase. The client wants to push out a single method to the production. Yes, I mean if there are 10 methods in a DLL the client wants to push a single method like FetchOrders(order id) into the production.

How can I go about doing that?

Comment: This is really a question about version control.  First and foremost, what revision control system are you using (if any)?

Answer (score 2):

Publish that one method if it's tested and accepted.

Branch the version (when using TFS) in case work needs done on the prod version while working on the full version.

Make sure the other functions aren't available in production.